# How to display youtube video in site

Tags: jquery, asp.net, video, video-processing

I want to display youtube video in my page.

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1
```

Above is url for it.

I wrote embed tag but not able to make it done properly.

Can I have embed tag or any other way to display you tube video using its url on my site?

Answer (score 0):

as shown here: [Embedding a Youtube video](http://forums.asp.net/p/1341599/2717427.aspx)

in the **.aspx** page

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelShowYouTubeVideo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

in **.aspx.cs** codebehind file:

```
// this is the YouTube Video ID, here you replace by 
// the code of the one you want to show
string VideoID = "nQJACVmankY";

// Here this code you show in the label the YouTube Video that you put the code
LabelShowYouTubeVideo.Text = "<object width='425' height='355'><param name='movie' value='http://www.youtube.com/v/" + VideoID + "'></param><param name='wmode' value='transparent'></param><embed src='http://www.youtube.com/v/" + VideoID + "' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' wmode='transparent' width='425' height='355'></embed></object>";
```

**Edit**: add the part: watch? to the url as needed. I copied what I found in the ASP.NET forum did not run it myself but people replied it works perfectly !

Comment: I have url like..http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR12Z8f1Dh8 so cannt i do something like directly pass url to object

Comment: why label ? better Literal and EnableViewState=false

Comment: This url is not working in above example.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR12Z8f1Dh8

Comment: I would suggest doing this on the client side if you don't need server side functionality - that will save you a round trip to the server.